# Running `mongod --config path` yields Error parsing command line

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongo-shell, replicaset

I was trying to create a mongodb (6.1.1) server with `mongod` with a custom config, but when I run `mongod --config path` the console yields `Error parsing command line:  Multiple occurrences of option "--config"`.

Running `mongod` alone or stuff like `mongod --port 12345` seems to create the server, so I'm not sure why it's giving an error parsing the command line. Any path I give (absolute, relative, invalid) it yields the same error. The alias `-f` yields the same.
I doubt it matters but I installed mongo through scoop.

Comment: Do you have spaces in your path? If yes, enclose it by quotes.

Comment: Make sure there isn't an alias for mongod.

Comment: @Joe `mongod -h` returns the mongo options so I assume it's fine

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit anything I pass it returns the same error, quotes or no quotes

Comment: I would also suspect an alias. How does the config file look like?

Comment: MongoDB consists only of 3 stand-alone executable. `mongos`, `mongod` and `mongosh` (which even needs to be installed separately). Actually there is no reason for a package manager, you can just copy these three files, that's it.

Comment: Try running `which mongod` to make sure it isn't aliased to something like `mongod -config /etc/mongod.conf`, and also check the type of that file to make sure it is the executable, not a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright found out the issue, it really is because of scoop.
Since one of scoop's objective is to prevent PATH polution, it writes an exe with the same name as the real executable, which runs behind the screen the real executable, with the help of the shim file.
`Get-Command mongod` yielded `C:\Users\Plancha\scoop\shims\mongod.exe`, and I thought that was the actual `mongod`. Turns out it isn't because it's in this `shims` folder. I understood this when I tried to copy and run this exe in the desktop (as kinda suggested by one of the commenters), and yielding `Could not read shim file`, leading me to make some further research about the package manager.

In conclusion, `mongod.shim` was:

```
path = "C:\Users\Plancha\scoop\apps\mongodb\current\bin\mongod.exe"
args = --config "C:\Users\Plancha\scoop\apps\mongodb\current\bin\mongod.cfg"
```

,
and the `mongod.exe` shim was simply passing the path, those args, and my additional args, leading to the multiple occurrences.
So to fix this, removing the args line was enough. I'll try and write a pull request to the main bucket.